# Using chain rule to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of an inverse sine, got negative of the actual solution

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, chain-rule, inverse-trigonometric-functions

### Problem

> Find $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$, where
> $y = \sin^{-1}\biggl(\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}\biggr)$

### Given solution

> $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \dfrac{2}{1+x^2}$

### My approach

I got the solution as $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = -\dfrac{2}{1+x^2}$ (negative of the given solution).

I took $t = \dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}$, so
$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x} = \dfrac{2(1-x^2)}{(1+x^2)^2}$.

Then I took $s = \sin^{-1}t$, so
$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}s}{\mathrm{d}t} 
= \dfrac{1}{(1-t^2)^{1/2}} = \dfrac{(x^2+1)}{(x-1)(x+1)}$
so
$$
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}s}{\mathrm{d}t} 
= 2\frac{1-x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} \cdot \frac{x^2+1}{(x-1)(x+1)}
= 2\frac{1-x}{(x-1)(1+x^2)}  
= -\frac{2}{1+x^2}.
$$

I googled solutions for this, most of them proceeded with substituting $x = \tan\theta$. I want to know why I'm getting negative of the actual answer, OR is both of these are the solutions for this?

My guess is that both positive and negatives are the solutions for this. In my approach I factorised the term $(1+x^2)^2 - (2x)^2$ under square root, which you would get after substituting $t$ with
$$
\frac{2x}{1+x^2}
$$
in $\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\mathrm{d}t}$, as $(x-1)^2 \cdot (x+1)^2$, therefore I ended up with factors $(1-x)$ and $(x-1)$ in numerator and denominator of the solution, respectively. If I instead factorised it as $(1-x)^2 \cdot (x+1)^2$, then I would have got the solution exact to the given one.

Comment: Please use mathjax to format your post -- that allows others to understand it much better.

Comment: Sorry I don't know mathjax scripting, I will learn it soon. Thanks to @SammyBlack for editing the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Both signs are correct.

The function has max/min at $x=\pm 1 $.

In the interval $|x|<1$ the slope is positive.

Outside this interval it is negative.

This often happens for inverse functions.

*Curious fact*

In the first quadrant slope changes $(1\to 0 \to -1)$ at maximum point $ (1,\dfrac{\pi}{2}).$

[image]

Comment: without plotting the graph, is there a way to find when (in terms of intervals of x) dy/dx of this problem is -ve, and when it is positive?

Comment: For small values of $x, ~\sin^{-1} x $ function graph shows slopes displaying either sign confirmed by its derivative also due to presence of a radical sign. $ \pm 1 / \sqrt{1-x^2}.$ However the answer given for derivative $ \dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}$ has sign  positive in first quadrant and negative in the third quadrant and so a max/min is expected. The given  answer is incomplete. However, I have no other idea now, how to fully approach it analytically.