# How to find when does the derivatives of functions involving some inverse trignometric functions be negative or positive?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse-trigonometric-functions

Consider y = cos<sup>-1</sup>(sin x):
I got dy/dx = +/- 1, but my textbook only mentions -1 as a solution. Here's how they arrived at it:
y = cos<sup>-1</sup>(sin x) = cos<sup>-1</sup>(cos(π/2-x)) = π/2 - x
=> dy/dx = -1

I got +/- 1 because I used the chain rule and ended up with a square root factor.

Here's How arrived at the solution:
[image: my approach]

Plotting the graph of dy/dx confirms that both +1 and -1 are solutions (at mutually exclusive intervals) [Graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vcv9ryfn9d).

I have seen more similar problems, all involving finding the derivative of some inverse trigonometric function ([another example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4852741/1182602)).

I couldn't find a way to find when does the derivative appears as positive or negative. Is there any way to find it (without plotting a graph)?

Comment: Unless the domain of $\cos^{-1}(\sin x)$ is restricted to $[-\pi/2,\pi/2],$ the book's answer is nonsense, as can be seen by plugging in any $x$ outside that interval. (The value of $\cos^{-1}$ can't be outside the interval $[0,\pi].$) They make the classic error of assuming that $\cos^{-1}$ cancels out $\cos$.

Comment: What were your steps in applying the chain rule? Try using MathJax, it will make the equations a lot easier to read (and eventually easier to write): http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: I asked about your application of the chain rule because when I do the chain rule I get a result that indicates exactly when the derivative is $+1$ and when it is $-1$, no graphing required, so I wonder what you did differently.

Comment: @DavidK Sorry for late reply. I guess the book just substistuted sin x with cos(pi/2 - x) and did the cancelling of cos and cos_inverse straight away. I have uploaded a pic regarding how I applied chain rule to get solution (sorry, I dont know MathJax, but will learn in free time). In my approach, I didn't get any info about when the solution is +ve or -ve.

Comment: No problem. I suspected that there was a simple way to fix the answer, but I needed to see your last couple of steps to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a good solution method right up to the point where you lose track of which sign to write in front of the answer.
The solution is simple: do not use $\pm\cos x$ as a substitution for $\sqrt{\cos^2 x}$.

A more accurate substitution is $\sqrt{\cos^2 x} = \lvert \cos x \rvert.$

The answer, in fact, is

$$ \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = - \frac{\cos}{\sqrt{\cos^2 x}}
 = - \frac{\cos}{\lvert \cos x \rvert}
= -\operatorname{sgn}(\cos x)$$

(where $\operatorname{sgn}$ is the "sign" function),
restricted to the domain
$\mathbb R \setminus \{ x \mid \cos x = 0\}$.
That is, the derivative is defined for all real numbers except the odd multiples of
$\frac\pi2,$ where $\cos x = 0$ and the function $\arccos(\sin x)$ is not differentiable.

Note that $\operatorname{sgn}(t)$ is usually defined to return $+1$, $-1$, or $0$ depending on whether $t$ is positive, negative, or zero (respectively), but in this exercise we will only ever see non-zero values of $\cos x$.
You could also just leave the answer in the form
$-\frac{\cos}{\lvert \cos x \rvert}$, which in my opinion is good enough
(perhaps even better, since it makes the domain restriction obvious).

Comment: Thank you! I'm always in confusion with the sqrt function. Putting +/- straight away removes info about solution's sign at different x. This solution helped me!!

Comment: Give yourself a pat on the back for doing the math better than the book, at least this time.

Comment: Not related to this question: suppose I have a term, let's say sin x. Is directly substituting it with sqrt(1 - sqr(cosx)) a valid approach? Or should I include +/- before sqrt(1 - sqr(cosx)) because sqrt only returns non-negative value, whereas sin x could be +ve or -ve?

Comment: In that case you do have to allow for both the positive and negative square root. You can use $\pm$ there, but if that leads to undesired uncertainty about the final answer, you can use other methods to keep track of the correct sign. Even just making a note that $\pm$ is $+$ when $\sin x \geq 0$ might be enough if you are consistent in how you keep track of $\pm$ and $\mp$ (like the way you did in your work in the question).